# Notify everyone in a Slack channel via Laravel

Tags: laravel, push-notification, notifications, slack, slack-api

I'm using Laravel Notifications functionality to post from our app to a Slack channel.

It works as I'd expect but would like this particular piece of functionality to '@channel' so that it pushes a notification to our users who have the Slack mobile app.

```
return (new SlackMessage)
        ->success()
        ->content("A ride request has been raised")
        ->attachment(function ($attachment) use ($ride) {
            $attachment->title($ride->name, route('ride', $ride->id))
                ->content($ride->pickup_address);
        });
```

I have tried changing the `to` method without any joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can customise the `to` method, that's not how it's done.

Instead you want to add the `<!channel>` keyword into your `content()` method like this:

`->content("Hey <!channel> someone has done something")`

Simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For Slack @ messages try:
`<!everyone|@everyone>` or `<!everyone>`.